# could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table with one primary key

Tags: python, database, user-interface, tkinter, sqlalchemy

I am working on a tkinter gui application and using sqlite as a storage schema,when trying to create a table after creating an engine facing this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBsvp.png)

**My code is as under**

```
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class Records(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Records"
    track_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
    weight = Column(String),
    pur_price = Column(String),
    pur_date = Column(String),
    dist_name = Column(String),
    cat = Column(String),
    polish = Column(String),
    making = Column(String),
    karat = Column(String)
```

**Package Versions**

```
Babel      2.9.0
pip        20.2.4
pytz       2020.4
setuptools 50.3.2
SQLAlchemy 1.3.11
tkcalendar 1.6.1
```

Comment: Could you have created the table and added the primary key in SQLAlchemy later?  SQLAlchemy will not automatically update the table structure with changes after the table had been created.

Comment: no table has not been created i have just added a first table and this error occurs